# How to read lines above and below a particular linenumber in java?

Tags: java, file-io

I need to parse a log file which is in `txt` format.

I need to match the String and read above and below lines of the matched String.

I need to do something similar to `grep -A 30 -B 50 'hello'`.

If You have any other suggestions to do it you are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use following code(uses java 5 api java.util.Scanner):

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("YourFilePath"));
    String prev = null;
    String current;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        current = scanner.nextLine();
        if (current.contains("YourRegEx"))
            break;
        else
            prev = current;
    }
    String next = scanner.nextLine();
```

You may want to add additional checks for `prev` being not null and Calling `scanner.hasNextLine()` before `String next = scanner.nextLine()`

Answer (score 1):

Read the file line by line, and match your string (either regexp or String.indexOf("")). Keep the previous n lines in memory so when you've matched your string you can print them. Use [BuffereReader.readLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) to read the file line by line  (note that using the BufferedReader is actually more complicated because you cannot jump back). 
Or for more flexibility [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). With this method you can mark your position, print the next m lines and then jump back to continue your search from where you left it.

Answer (score 1):

pseudocode:

```
initialize a Queue
for each line
    if line matches regex
        read/show lines from queue;
        read/show next lines;
    else {
        if queue size > 30
             queue.remove() // removes head of the queue
        add this line to queue;
    }
```

You can use [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) to read a file line by line, [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to check the line against a regular expression, and [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) to store previous lines.

Comment: you need to print the previous 30 lines and the next 50 for each occurrence of the search string. Your pseudo-code does not really do that...

Comment: Before being edited, the question did not mention 30 lines - just "above and below lines". Editing the code now.

Comment: Yes, I deducted that from the "grep -A 30 -B 50 'hello'" :D